# How can i clear messages via slash command in Pycord?

Tags: attributeerror, pycord, purge

Since Pycord is kind of a Discord.py fork, i thought i could just use `ctx.purge(limit=X)`, but it does'nt work. Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```py
@bot.command()

async def purge(ctx, amount: int):

    await ctx.purge(limit=amount)

    await ctx.respond(f"Purged {amount} messages.")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a fork of discord.py so it will carry over a lot of its attributes and methods. `discord.Interaction` has an attribute for the message and using the message attribute we can retrieve the channel:

https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Interaction.message

```py
message = interaction.message
channel = message.channel

# To purge:
channel.purge(amt)
```

Purge is an function of discord.TextChannel read more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge)

If this doesn't work you can print `message` variable and see the attributes it has.